# eli5 explaining prediction XGBoost model

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

I don't understand why I have a feature named BIAS in the contributing features.

I read the doc and I find

> " In each column there are features and their weights. Intercept
>   (bias) feature is shown as  in the same table "

But I don't understand what intercepting bias mean here.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is related to the way `ELI5` computes the weights.

`XGBoost` outputs scores only for leaves (you can see it via `booster.dump_model(…, with_stats=True)`), so the `XGBoost` explainer implementation in `ELI5` starts reconstructing pseudo leaves scores for every node across all the trees. These pseudo leaves scores are basically the average leaf score you would expect if stopping the tree at this node level, thus the average of all children leaves weighted by their cover in the training set.

This algorithm also applies to the root nodes of the trees, which are similarly assigned pseudo leaves scores. At the root node level, this score is the average score you may end up going through the tree. Summed across all the trees, this sum of all root nodes scores is the average score you may get going through all the trees (the one that will be applied a sigmoid to translate into a probability). This is what `ELI5` puts into `<BIAS>`.

So you can understand `<BIAS>` as the expected average score output by the model, based on the distribution of the training set.

The `<BIAS>` will change if you modify your `base_score` parameter (for instance in the case of an imbalanced binary classification, you may change the default `0.5` to something closer to your target rate, and the `<BIAS>` should get closer to `0`).

EDIT: maybe it's clearer with the visual explanation from this blog (`baseline` is equivalent to `<BIAS>`) https://medium.com/applied-data-science/new-r-package-the-xgboost-explainer-51dd7d1aa211

Comment: Thank you ! that's very helpful, do you have an idea how xgboost calculate scores for terminal leafs for classification problems ?

Comment: Not an easy answer! Formulas & proofs are explained here: http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model.html -- leaves scores are in the `w` vector (in the 'Model complexity' chapter)

Comment: Is it bad if ELi5 shows <BIAS> as the most important feature?

Comment: It might mean your predictions, on this given dataset, are not generating a lot of variance, in absolute value, when compared to the bias of the model. Overall this is typically no a property you want for your model (as any classifier, you want it to discriminate as much as possible between cases), but qualifying it as bad might be harsh as it depends on the use case and the dataset on which the contributions of variables is evaluated (e.g. imagine a dataset where all rows are very similar, if not identical). I would first adjust `base_score` so that `<BIAS>` is close to 0 on the training set.